# Почему при блокирови PHP-сессии сайт подвисает у всех пользователей?

Tags: php, nginx, сессия, php-fpm

На каждой странице сайта есть - чтение данных из сессий, на некоторых запись - для сохранении кастомых настроек. Если у **одного** авторизованного пользователя (одной сессии) - сайт долго грузиться (по причине обновления сессионных данных) - то это затрагивает **всех** пользователей сайта.

В качестве сессии используется файловая система.

Дополнительно: есть ли резон переписать всё с завершением сессий (session_write_close), если скрипты выполняются быстро, учитывая что проблема "тормозов" должна касаться лишь одной сессии, а не всех одновременно.

В slowlog php-fpm выдает следующее:

```
flock() /.../.../Session_files_driver.php:180
```

Session_files_driver.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: стаким подходом это сайт для одного пользователя. По хорошему надо выкидывать все что есть и переписать по человечески

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev почему для одного?

Comment: 1. Есть подозрение что `$session_id` у всех пользователей один и тот же. Поэтому локает эта строчка. 2. Возможно, что запущен не php-fmp, который входящие запросы раскидывает по отдельным воркерам, а встроенный php сервер - он работает в один поток, я про `php -S localhost:8000 router.php` (хотя не было бы слоу лога. но проверьте)